# MySQL table for saving a quantity to a 1:M relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a tables called `invoice`, `item` and `invoice_item`. The `invoice` item tables has `invoice_id` and `item_id` columns to store a 1:M type relationship, where an invoice can have many items.

Now I want to somehow store information for item quantity. Would it be suitable to create an `invoice_item_quantity` table, that store `invoice_id`, `item_id` and `invoice_item_quantity` values, respectively? Or would there be a more optimal solution?

I could be over-engineering this, but adding something like a `item_quantity` column to the `invoice` table won't work cause you can have many different types of items, so there would be no context there.

I basically need a way to store a model like this:

- Invoice

  - Item 1 x 5
  - Item 2 x 2
  - Item 3 x 15

How can I optimally store the quantities in the model above?

Comment: why not add quantity to invoice_item table?  If you think about it the invoice_item breaks up a M:M relationship an item could be on many invoices and an invoice could have many items.  since this table is about the association of an item to an invoice, it makes sense that the attributes associated to that relationship (such as quantity) would be present.  You may want to have an "OrderQTY and a ModifiedOrderQty incase someone says that they want 10 call and say no make that 7 so you can keep track of variance (maybe it will go up to 20 too!)

Comment: Other attributes could Include where to ship (maybe the lines have separate destinations?  or a status of the line or how it's to be delivered, or sourcing vendor, or a planend ship date, or in care of (in case the order goes to 1 address but different people at a line level) ... you get the idea.

Comment: Good point xQbert, I understand your comment now that Karl has given his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship between the `invoice` and `item` tables, and that you are using a junction table to support this with the `invoice_item` table (this junction has a one-to-many relationship with both `invoice` and `item`).

If you are looking for a typical, normalized database design, then storing the quantity on the `invoice_item` table is good. Another good idea would be to make the invoice ID and the item ID a compound primary key on your junction table.

Comment: Ahh I didn't think about that, I suppose the `invoice_item` table is already a junction table, so it would be kind of redundant having `invoice_item_quantity` just to store one extra value. So with that being said, could I then add any new fields after `quantity` to that same table?

Comment: New fields that support/are unique to the relationship and maintain proper cardinality between material and item.  So I wouldn't want to explode out the materials used in making the item here.  Nor would I want to show the customer who placed the order here as it belongs on the order.  But information such as Ship To (to override order if separate by item) may make sense.  Think xmas.  I buy gifts for me and my nephews who live in a different state. I don't want them all shipped to me and placing separate orders negates my discount for over $50 purchase.  So won't you please ship to two places